# 3D geometric interpretations of matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, inverse, geometric-interpretation

In the question [Geometric interpretations of matrix inverses](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295250/geometric-interpretations-of-matrix-inverses/), I provided a visual answer for the $2 \times 2$ case, showing the relationship between the matrices $A$ and $A^{-1}$ in terms of the size and shapes of the parallelograms of their row vectors.

I've completed a parallel demonstration for the inverse of a $3 \times 3$ matrix, shown below, but I would like to characterize the relationship more completely than I did before.  For example,

- What is a general statement of the orthogonality relations between the (row) vectors $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ that define the paralellepiped of $A$ to the corresponding vectors $a^1$, $a^2$, and $a^3$ of $A^{-1}$?
- Are there interesting relations between dot (inner) products and cross-products of the vectors $a_i$ and $a^i$?
- How can one describe the relationships between the **faces** of $A$ and $A^{-1}$?

In this example, I use the following matrix A, whose determinant is 2.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    1
[2,]    0    2    0
[3,]    1    0    2
```

Its inverse is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2  0.0   -1
[2,]    0  0.5    0
[3,]   -1  0.0    1
```

Here is a 3D plot of $A$ and $A^{-1}$, with axes and some corresponding vertex points labeled.  Faces are colored in the same way on both views.

[image]

Here is an animated version of the same, rotating around the $z$ axis.

[image]

In case anyone is interested, these figures are done in R, and the code for this example is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/friendly/eaff419da573c492a56a4ea05b2f4868)

Comment: Very nice, both the drawings and the code.

Comment: @user101089 I tried to use the code that you provided but it is giving me the following error:

Error in movie3d(spin3d(rpm = 15), duration = 4, movie = "inv-demo", dir = ".") : 
  could not find function "movie3d"